# Error al hacer push en repositorio

Tags: git, github, git-push

Al intentar subir mi rama al repositorio remoto me aparece el siguiente error, ya intente
git config --global http.sslVerify true pero aun sigue sin funcionar.

[image: error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate

Comment: intenta con `git config --global http.sslBackend schannel` para que se comunique con el almacén de certificados de Windows